# Hide an action from IntelliJ IDEA action search

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I develop a plugin that provides some actions to IntelliJ IDEA.
Is it possible to hide an action from "global action search"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

No, what is the use case to hide is specifically there?